# Adding value to submitbutton with image

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this problem : 
I have a submit button defined as follows  :

```
 <input  type="submit" name="actionName" value="search" />
 <input  type="submit" name="actionName" value="New" />
```

both submit buttons are included in an Ajax beginForm:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PFSearch", "Payer", ajaxOptions))
```

In the controller ... based on the actionName string provided .. i do different actions based on the value of button pressed within my Ajax befin form :

```
if (actionName="search")
{
//do something
}
```

And everything works like a charm .. until i want to add i want to add an image to the class of my submit button :

```
  <input class="search" type="submit" name="actionName" value="search" />
  <input class="search" type="submit" name="actionName" value="New" />
```

My search tab looks like this : [image]

As you can clearly see my main impediment is that by adding value ... the text appears over my image. 
**How can i make those button act differently within my ajax begin form considering that giving value to the buttons doesn't work ?** Any alternatives or workarounds are appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: use image-tags, a hidden input field and an onclick-event with which you write in the hidden field which image was clicked and submit the form

Comment: <input class="search" id="btnNew" type="submit" name="actionName" actionname="New" /> and i added : <img class="search" onclick="function(){$('#btnNew').click();}" /> but i get this error : Error: function statement requires a nameSource File:function(){$('#btnNew').click();}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please give us a link to your project's demo? And try to use some `margin`, `padding` and `background-position:center;`

Comment: Its not a css issue ... it a mvc one... I'll remove the css tag

Comment: I think you'll find it is a CSS issue?

Comment: my bad ... actually ... this was the ay to do it :bumpinthehead. Thanks ! I'll award bounty in 3 hours ( at least thats what the message said when i tried)